# My drivers are in the archive manager how do I move it to a place that the video card will reconize it

Tags: drivers, video, matrox

I suppose to load my Matrox g400 drivers (4.4.0.tar.gz) to either update manager, ubuntu software center or synaptic package manager from the archive manager (I have it there now), is the way to load it to a place were my video card can find it or address it.

Comment: i guess you will have to build your own package

Comment: Best advice is to follow the documentation that came with the proprietary driver.

Comment: Hello, this question has no information and activity for a very long time. I am closing it for now. If by any reason you think this question is still viable or useful in anyway or that there is still a good chance it will be answered please flag it to a moderator or add a comment with the reason(s) why you want it open. Regards